# Check expression input parameter for Setup in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I want to Moq a method that looks like this:

```
OrderAttrTypeRepository.Get(attributeType => attributeType.Description == property.Key);
```

And I would like to compare the invocation argument for this method depending on property.Key

I'm trying this:

```
 Expression<Func<OrderAttrType, bool>> saveObject;
 Expression<Func<OrderAttrType, bool>> criteria = y => y.Description == "ServiceCharge";
 Mock.Setup(x => x.OrderAttrTypeRepository.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<OrderAttrType, bool>>>()))
 .Callback<Expression<Func<OrderAttrType, bool>>>(i => saveObject = i)
 .Returns<Expression<Func<OrderAttrType, bool>>>(filter =>
  {
   if (Utility.ExpressionComparer.AreEqual(filter, criteria))
      return "Whatever";
   else
      return null;
  })
```

When I run the test, however, I always get a null. Even though the method is called with property.key = "ServiceCharge".

In the saveObject Object, the expression body looks like this:

```
attributeType.Description == value(Quipu.Eba.Service.UtilityPaymentService+<>c__DisplayClass53).property.Key)
```

That's the reason why the expressions are not evaluated as they were the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is OrderAttrTypeRepository.Get declared?

Comment: Is part of an interface and it looks like T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression). The inner declaration does not matter for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself now I found the problem.

`property.Key` is a variable, so, when evaluated as an expression, it is transformed to `value(Quipu.Eba.Service.UtilityPaymentService+<>c__DisplayClass53).property.Key)`

If `property.key` was a constant string with value `"ServiceCharge"`, then it will be transformed as expected with the value of the constant and I would be able to compare the expressions.

So, I will have to focus the problem in another way, because, whatever the value for the variable property.key is, it's always transformed to their reference and not the value, and that means, as far as I know, there's no way I can distinguish the expressions.